# Add columns name of datagridview to standalone Combobox Control

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview

I have filled the datagridview `dgvDisplay` by datatable `dTable`. I want to add the Datagridview **columns name** to another control **Combobox** `cmbSearchColumn` as items. How would I do that?

```
dTable = LoadDTable();
dgvDisplay.DataSource = dTable;
cmbSearchColumn.DataSource = ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `List<string>` of the column names from your `DataTable` like so:

```
List<string> colNames = dTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToList());
```

Then you can set the `DataSource` of your `ComboBox` to this `List<string>` of your column names:

```
cmbSearchColumn.DataSource = colNames;
```

If you want the header text of the datagridview:

```
List<string> dgvHeaders = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
      dgvHeaders.Add(column.HeaderText);
}
```

Comment: How can I get the column header text ?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan I gave you that in the first line of code in my answer. You `cast` each item of the Columns property of your datatable to `DataColumn` and select it's `ColumnName` property which is of type `string`.

Comment: DataTable column name is different from header text of columm. e.g column name is `SName` but column header text is `Student Name`. How to get header text as well?

Comment: I know how to use it. but i didn't get ur point in above comment.

Comment: @muhammadrizwan if you want the headers of your datagridview, see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 options to do it 
(or you can use LINQ as presented in Ryan Wilson answer)

```
private void Myfunction()
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

    // Option 1:
    for(int i = 0;i< dTable.Columns.Count;i++)
    {
        cmbSearchColumn.Items.Add(dTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    }

    // Option 2:
    List<string> Cols = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Cols.Add(dTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    }
    cmbSearchColumn.DataSource = cmbSearchColumn;
}
```

Comment: How can I get the column header text ?